# React function uses old state used when creating instance of subcomponent

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a ToDo component and an Item component in my react app. I noticed that when I trigger my onDelete function from my Item component, it only has the tdList state variable in the state it was in when I created the item component. Why does this happen and how can I fix this issue.

```
function ToDo() {
    const [tdList, setTD] = useState([]);
    const [item, setItem] = useState("");
    const onDelete = (id) => {
        // console.log(id);
        console.log(tdList);
        for(let i=0; i<tdList.length; i++){
            if (tdList[i].props.id == id){
                // setTD(tdList.splice(i, 1))
            }
        }
        // setTD(tdList.splice())
    };
    const onHandleSubmit = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        setTD([...tdList, (<Item id={itemsAdded} item={item} delete={onDelete} />)]);
        setItem('');
        // console.log(tdList);
        itemsAdded++;
    };
...more code...
```

Comment: use React.useCallback and add dependency of state. Read about it at https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't put React components into state. It breaks the natural order of how they're supposed to work and can make the control flow that's been written *very* difficult to understand. Instead, into state, put only *the values needed to create React components from* later - and when returning from the component, create the components from that state.

For your code, you could do something like:

```
const [lastIdUsed, setLastIdUsed] = useState(-1); // use this instead of reassigning a non-React itemsAdded variable
const [tdData, setTdData] = useState([]);
const onDelete = (id) => {
    // use `.filter`, not `.splice` in React - don't mutate state
    setTdData(tdData.filter(tdItem => tdItem.id !== id));
};
const onHandleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    setTdData([...tdData, { id: lastIdUsed + 1, item }]);
    setItem('');
    setLastIdUsed(lastIdUsed + 1);
};
const tds = tdData.map(
    tdItem => <Item id={tdItem.id} item={tdItem.item} delete={onDelete} />
);
```

And then with the `tds`, return them or interpolate them into the JSX at the end.

Only create components right before you're going to return them.